# Confused about wiki comment about Fréchet-Urysohn spaces

Tags: general-topology

On the [wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space) for Fréchet-Urysohn spaces it says

> Fréchet-Urysohn spaces are the most general class of spaces for which sequences suffice to determine all topological properties of subsets of the space. That is, Fréchet-Urysohn spaces are exactly those spaces for which knowledge of which sequences converge to which limits (and which sequences do not) suffices to completely determine the space's topology. Every Fréchet-Urysohn space is a sequential space but not conversely.

But from my understanding this is the characterization of sequential spaces, which Fréchet-Urysohn spaces are a proper subset of.

What am I missing?

Comment: Well, the statement is inherently imprecise: what does it mean for this "knowledge" to "determine" the topology?  I would agree that it is misleading, though, and it would be far more reasonable to interpret that statement as describing sequential spaces instead.